# In golang, how do I protect my own lock safe from being destroyed by the caller?

Tags: go

I try use "sync.mutex" protect my func,but i found that the lock still uses the caller to destroy it.

```
var mutex sync.mutex
```

This is error:

```
//caller use
func a() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go b(i)
    }
}

//My func
func b(i int) {
    mutex.Lock()
    fmt.Println(i)
    mutex.Unlock()
}
```

this is success,but destroyed my encapsulation method:

```
//caller use
func a() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        mutex.Lock()
        go b(i)
    }
}

//my func
func b(i int) {
    fmt.Println(i)
    mutex.Unlock()
}
```

Thanks

Comment: A mutex should be locked & unlocked from the same code block if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> - the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

Put the function in its own package and don't export the mutex. For example.

```
package b

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex

func B(i int) {
    mutex.Lock()
    fmt.Println(i)
    mutex.Unlock()
}
```

To use,

```
package a

import "b"

func a() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go b.B(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i may have misled by sync.Cond.wait(). When goroutines is waiting, it not block other goroutines.I will change my code try again.

Comment: Can not, i tried it. The same is not secure, it is a strange thing.Maybe I should go more in-depth study Mutex and Goroutines

Comment: @tiango: A common method to manage goroutines is a `sync.WaitGroup` with `Add`, `Wait`, and `Done` methods. See the Go Tour section on concurrency: https://tour.golang.org

Comment: Thank your help, i'm so fool, i confuse the synchronization lock and the mutex. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, all the calls to `go b(i)` are called in `a`'s loop, but the loop can be finished before any of the goroutines have a chance to start, so if main returns, then all those goroutines stop.

In the second example, the mutex locks and doesn't unlock until `Unlock` is called in each of the `b` goroutines. The result is that the calls are completely sequential since each iteration of the loop in `a` can't start until the last iteration's `b` goroutine finishes and calls `Unlock`.

A better practice in Go would be for your b function to take in a pointer to the mutex along with the number passed in, so in your original example it would look like:

```
//caller use
func a() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            b(&mutex, i)
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

//My func
func b(mutex *sync.Mutex, i int) {
    mutex.Lock()
    fmt.Println(i)
    mutex.Unlock()
}
```

Which would remove reliance on a global variable and also guarantee that all calls to `b` are using the exact same mutex since we pass in a pointer to one mutex

Comment: Won't this destroy the lock? `func a() { for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { go b(&mutex, i); mutex.Unlock() } }`

Comment: @Andy Haskell You are right. Other question, "sync.Cond.wait()"  not block other goroutines. I think it is a strange thing.Maybe I should go more in-depth study Mutex and Goroutines. Why the mutex cannot guarantee the safety of the method? How can I better understand golang lock?

Comment: @tiango I've never used a sync.Cond before. I use Go on the job and the parts of concurrency I use regularly are `Mutex`, `RWMutex`, `WaitGroup`, and channels (which internally use a mutex). This is a good post on understanding WaitGroups https://medium.com/@matryer/very-basic-concurrency-for-beginners-in-go-663e63c6ba07 and this post has an example of mutexes https://gobyexample.com/mutexes. Where are you on learning Go right now, and have you used concurrency in other languages?

Comment: Btw updated the code in my example to add a WaitGroup

Comment: @AndyHaskell Thank your help, i'm so fool, i confuse the synchronization lock and the mutex. Thank you very much again.